# AWS Beanstalk document directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've successfully uploaded my application to AWS Beanstalk and its environment URL is also working. But whenever I change any PHP scripts under /var/www/html/ it does not reflects changes.

I'm not sure about directory location of Beanstalk application and assuming its a /var/www/html/ am trying this.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you deploy your application to a PHP-based environment running in Elastic Beanstalk, your application code is stored in `/var/www/html/`. This can be changed by changing the `DocumentRoot` setting in the Elastic Beanstalk web console or via `.ebextensions` settings.

When you deploy changes, it takes a few minutes for the deployment process to complete — it isn't instantaneous.

> […] whenever I change any PHP scripts under /var/www/html/ it does not reflects changes.

How are you making these changes?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now. I've changed using vim editor.

Comment: What about windows server path ?

Answer (score 1):

You should, of course, deploy the changed code using

```
eb deploy
```

You can set the document root in a file in the .ebextensions folder by using this:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
  option_name: document_root
  value: /root/folder/relative/to/var/www/html
```

Comment: This can also be set in the .ebextensions according to this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html